# How to repaint a QTreeView after calling QItemSelectionModel::select?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreeview, qitemselectionmodel

I have a QTreeView using a custom QAbstractItemModel. I update the tree view selection with

```
treeView->selectionModel()->select(selection, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
```

Which should also emit the signal selectionChanged for the tree view to receive. My issue is the tree view doesn't refresh until I interact with it with my cursor.

I've tried calling treeView->update() but it doesn't make a difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you done this: `connect(selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&)),treeView, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()));`?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I've realised I was blocking the QItemSelectionModel signals further up my chain to avoid repeat calls of functions.

Comment: It's nice to know that you solved your problem. Please, ask yourself how worth this Q/A is for future readers (and under what circumstances it will be found if somebody has a similar issue). May be, it's better to delete Q as well as A.